# AngularJS ng-model array

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with multiple select fields which are defined by the back-end and rendered by Angular.

Here's the HTML snipped to render them:

```
        <div ng-repeat="area in areas">
            <label>{{area.areaName}} :</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="area[area.areaId]" ng-options="x for x in preferences">
            </select>
        </div>
```

All the select boxes are rendered correctly, but am I using the ng-model correctly?

When I try and test it with this:

```
<p>Area 1 {{area[1]}}</p>
```

the display is not updated when I select a value, but I was hoping it would reflect the new selection.

Comment: ng-model="area" and whatever you select will be in area. Add a track by $index to the ng-repeat

Comment: This looks incorrect, please provide sample for preferences and areas.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these,display will be updated

```
<div ng-repeat="area in areas">
            <label>{{area.areaName}} :</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="area[$index]" ng-options="x for x in preferences">
            </select>
        </div>
```

OR

```
<div ng-repeat="area in areas">
            <label>{{area.areaName}} :</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="area" ng-options="x for x in preferences">
            </select>
        </div>
```